# How do you redirect to a popup using php and not javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, api, twitter

I find tons of ways to do it in javascript, but I need to call smack in the middle of a php script.

```
<form action="" method="POST" target='popup' onsubmit="window.open('','popup','width=700,height=400,left=200,top=200,scrollbars=1')">
        Send a message  : <input type="text" name="twitmessage"><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="twitter" value="My Posting Text">Would you like to send to Twitter?<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="facebook" value="Stuff to Post to facebook">Would you like to post to Facebook?<br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_cycle" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['twitmessage'] = $_POST['twitmessage'];

if(isset($_POST['submit_cycle'])) {
        if($_POST['twitter']){
                header("location: ../index.php?p=members");
        }
        if($_POST['facebook']){
                header("location: ../index.php?p=paybill");
        }else{
                echo "Something bad happened";
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: what does "redirect to a popup" mean ?

Comment: need a lot better explanation of your issue...doesn't make a bit of sense currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach. Maybe I didn't get your intention right.

To open the twitter dialog in a different window you could simply add `target=_blank` to your form.

The rest should be the same as above.

To create a sized window, create a new, named window. Then scale it and set the target of the form to the window's name.

Comment: I edited the code and the above is almost perfect. any thoughts as to how to get 2 (one, two) popup windows for if someone selects 2 options? I can get one just fine, the second stumps me.

Comment: bind a javascript to it and loop the options an call window.open for every option ? 

store the window instances in variables to have access to them

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Opening a window is a client-side operation which cannot be performed using PHP. That's by principle.

You can generate the JS, which will open a new window on the client-side.

```
<script>
    window.open('<?php echo htmlentities($url); ?>')
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. That does appear to be the best and only way.

Comment: Just take in mind that using window.open will open a "classic" popup which will often be blocked by default of all of the modern browsers while an overlay using javascript and making an AJAX request to the server side will not